# Laravel 5.6 Cache::rememberForever not caching data with variable key

Tags: php, laravel-5, memcached

Using Laravel 5.6 to cache queries using the memcached driver. When I use a variable in the key name, the results are never cached and it uses the database call but the same query works with 'test' as the key name. What am I missing?

Does not work...

```
/**
 * Get one id
 * @param $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null|object|static
 */
public function get($id)
{
    return Cache::rememberForever('species-' . $id, function () use ($id) {
        return AnimalSpecies::where('id', $id)->with('subspecies', 'morphs', 'combos', 'localities')->first();
    });
}
```

Does work...

```
/**
 * Get one id
 * @param $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null|object|static
 */
public function get($id)
{
    return Cache::rememberForever('test', function () use ($id) {
        return AnimalSpecies::where('id', $id)->with('subspecies', 'morphs', 'combos', 'localities')->first();
    });
}
```

Comment: try with `'species_' . $id`

Answer (score 0):

My problem was an incorrect variable was being passed though `$id` and it was a string with a space in it, which wasn't an allowed character. Once I passed the correct numerical `$id` caching worked perfect.